# Exclude Xpath from other Xpath

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, xpath, xpath-1.0

If you have two Xpaths you can join them with the `|` operator to return both their results in one result set. This essentially gives back the union of the two sets of elements. The example below gives back all `div`s and all `span`s on a website:

```
//div | //span
```

What I need is the difference (subsection). I need all elements in the first Xpath group that are not in the second Xpath group. So far I have seen that there is an `except` operator but that only works in Xpath2. I need an Xpath1 solution. I have seen that the `not` function might help but I was not able to make it work.

As an example imagine the following:

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
```

In this example I would have the Xpath group `//tr/td`. I would want to **exclude** `<td>1</td>` and `<td>4</td>`. Although there are many ways to solve the problem I am specifically looking for a solution where I can say in an Xpath: "Here is a group of elements and exclude this group of elements from it".

UPDATE:
As it was pointed out, the example above did not give a proper representation for what I wanted to achieve, so I am giving another example here.

On a website I collect all HTML div elements with: `//div`. Here I get 645 div elements. I also have 3 specific xpaths for 3 div elements I want to exclude form the result of 645:

```
//span[@class="sp"]/p/div[1]
//html/body/div/span/div
//p[@id="para"]/div/p/div
```

So what I want to achieve is get back 1 xpath which contains all divs on a webpage, excluding the ones I have specified in the other xpaths. The result should be 642 div elements.

This has been answered, however I am leaving here the update for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach realizing this is using the `self::` axis and the `not()` operator in a predicate:
For example, with an XML like this

```
<root>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>    
    <dr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </dr>    
</root>
```

you can use this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//tr/td[not(self::*=//dr/td)]
```

which can be shortened to

```
//tr/td[not(.=//dr/td)]
```

The resulting nodeset is as desired

```
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>5</td>
```

The XPath expression selects all elements of the first part and checks in the predicate if every element itself (`self::*` or `.`) is in the second part. If it is, it will be excluded (`not(...)`).

You can also apply this approach to attribute nodes. In this case you have to use the `.`, because `self::*` is more specific and only selects elements. So you could replace `self::*` by `.`, but not the other way round. (The most general axis would be `self::node()`.)

Comment: Using "=" does not compare nodes by identity, it compares them by value. This answer, although accepted, is therefore WRONG. It is entirely possible for two quite different td elements (for example `<td>X</td>` and `<td><p>X</p></td>`) to be equal when compared using "=". Comparing nodes using `=` can also be incredibly expensive if they have large subtrees.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logic **and** and **not** operators here.
For your specific example you can use the following XPath

```py
"//tr/td[not(text()=`1`)][not(text()=`4`)]"
```

Comment: Apologies if I had not written my example properly. Where I will need this I can't use the text of the elements. I can only use the tag name and the attributes of the tags. How would you tackle it then?

Comment: But in your XML example I see no attributes of those `td`s except the text values. In case in real XML there are such attributes / tag names - please update your XML example

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 2.0+ there is an operator for this: `except`. If E and F are general expressions returning sets of nodes, then `E except F` returns all nodes selected by E that are not selected by F.

There's no convenient way of doing the same thing in XPath 1.0, but the rather cumbersome (and potentially expensive) expression `E[count(.|F) != count(F)]` is equivalent (though you need to take care about the context for evaluation of F).

In many practical cases you can achieve the desired effect with a filter predicate, for example `//td[not(ancestor::tr)]`.